# Proving that $x \not\in B \cap C \iff x \not\in B \lor x \not\in C$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've got a set theory question. I'm required to show that $x \not\in B \cap C$ if and only if $x \not\in B$ or $x \not\in C$. I decided to call the universal set $S$ (which contains both and $B$ and $C$ and supposed that $B \cap C \neq \varnothing$) and went along the following reasoning. Is it correct?
$$\begin{aligned} x \not\in B \cap C & \iff (x \not\in B) \land (x \not\in C) \\ & \iff (x \in B') \land (x \in C') \\ & \iff (x \in S-B) \land (x \in S-C) \\ & \iff x \not\in B \cup C \\ & \iff (x \not\in B) \lor (x \not\in C) \end{aligned}$$ (Where $B'$ is the complement of $B$ in $S$.)

Thanks in advance for any replies. ^_^

Comment: Your first equivalence is wrong !
$$x\notin B\cap C \iff \neg(x\in B\cap C)\iff\neg(x\in B \wedge x\in C)\iff (x\notin B)\vee (x\notin C)$$
Your inference proves for every propositions $p,q$ we must have : $$p\wedge q \iff p\vee q$$
This is absurd, isn't it ?

Comment: The whole thing is a bit pointless, because what you want to proof is just the negation of the definition of $B \cap C$, i.e. the negation of $x\in B \cap C \Leftrightarrow x \in B \land x \in C$. And yes, your first inference is definitely wrong.

Comment: Ah, of course! Thank you @FardadPouran. If you want to post that up as an answer, I'd be more than willing to accept it. I wouldn't say it's pointless, GDumphart. A question is worth what you can learn from doing it and I see where my mistake was, so it was fairly useful. ^_^

Comment: @KhallilBenyattou Yes sure, it's nice as an exercise. But it's similar to the following: "Define Sarah as the girl over there. Prove that girls other than Sarah are not over there." You agree that such a thing is a bit pointless, don't you? :D

Comment: @KhallilBenyattou, thank you. Bit Timbuc's answer is better ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**By definition**, we have that

$$x\in B\cap C\stackrel{def.}\iff x\in B\;\;\wedge\,x\in C$$

The logical negation of the above is

$$x\notin B\cap C\iff \neg\left(x\in B\wedge\,x\in C\right)$$

Now you just need to convince yourself that the logical negation of the conjuction is the disjunction of *the negation of each factor*, i.e.

$$\neg\left(A\wedge B\right) \equiv\neg A\vee \neg B$$

The easiest way to see this is with truth tables.

Comment: Is it correct to write $=$ in the final line you've typed up, @Timbuc? I thought it would've been $\iff$ instead.

Comment: You're right, @KhallilBenyattou. In fact I tried to write the three lines for "logical equivalence", but it didn't come up correctly. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the reply, @Timbuc. I've convinced myself that the two are logically equivalent with a truth table. ^_^

Comment: It's called [DeMorgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), which also tells us, in logic $\lnot (B \lor C) = \lnot B \land \lnot C$, and correspondingly, as it applies to set theory, $$x \notin (B\cap C) \iff \lnot(x \in B \land x\in C) \iff x \notin B \lor x \notin C \iff x\in B^c \lor x \in C^c \iff x \in (B^c\cup C^c)$$